# proftpd not starting

Tags: linux, ftp

proftp is not working in my server which has Directadmin control panel. I restarted it. But failed.

```
[root@S25 scripts]# service proftpd restart
Shutting down proftpd:                                     [FALLÓ]
Starting proftpd:  - warning: "ProFTPd" address/port (148.136.52.247:21) already in use by "ProFTPd"
 - warning: "ProFTPd" address/port (148.136.52.247:21) already in use by "ProFTPd"
 - warning: "ProFTPd" address/port (148.136.52.247:21) already in use by "ProFTPd"
 - warning: "ProFTPd" address/port (148.136.52.247:21) already in use by "ProFTPd"
 - warning: "ProFTPd" address/port (148.136.52.247:21) already in use by "ProFTPd"
 - warning: "ProFTPd" address/port (148.136.52.247:21) already in use by "ProFTPd"
 - warning: "ProFTPd" address/port (148.136.52.247:21) already in use by "ProFTPd"
148.136.52.246 - ProFTPD terminating (signal 11)
148.136.52.246 - FTP session closed.
/bin/bash: line 1: 21416 Violación de segmento  proftpd
                                                           [FALLÓ]
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the following things:

1) Ensure IP's in the server are setup correctly
2) make sure that the server ip is setup with the hostname in the /etc/hosts file.
3) make sure that the server ip is *not* in the /etc/proftpd.vhosts.conf as a VirtualHost

You can reffer the following url too:

http://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=24

Regards,
Ajo

Comment: Thank you very much. The issue was due to the main server ip in the config file. I have removed it and the proftpd started.